# I have a larger screen attached to my laptop

Tags: 13.10

I have a larger screen attached to my laptop, which is a Toshiba, when I close the lid both screens close into sleep mode, what command do I use to stop this.
I am a new user on Ubuntu 13.10, I am also new to Linux OS.
With thanks

Pietboks

Comment: Do you also have a separate keyboard? If so: press the spacebar. The screen will go out of sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have this, too, with my laptop. Here it suffices to just move the mouse and the 2nd screen goes out of sleep.